# JQuery - Don't add hover class on button success/errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form with some JQuery validation and button effects. When you hover, the Submit text moves to the side and shows an arrow. When you click without submitting the form, you get an error (red button) and when it's successful, you get a green button with a tick saying thank you.

I only want the hover class to run/work when there's no error or success classes.

I have tried using, but I don't think it's the best way to achieve this?

```
if ( !$(".contourNavigation").children().hasClass("success") ) {
    return $(this).addClass("hover");
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t5k2j9uw/)

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // JQuery Validate

    // name
    $("#abc6b8ed-5c99-460c-bd80-257747b07466").rules("add", {
          required: true,
          messages: {
            required: "Mandatory"
          }
        }) 

    // email
    $("#dbd7b2e5-6a26-413a-b738-bc7441e4eace").rules("add", {
      required: true,
      messages: {
        required: "Mandatory"
      }
    })  

    // message
    $("#05ce7d9f-b381-4c14-bc37-36f0270fc19a").rules("add", {
      required: true,
      messages: {
        required: "Mandatory"
      }
    })

    //Intercept Submit button in order to make ajax call instead of a postback
    $('#contactForm').preventDoubleSubmission();
});

// jQuery plugin to prevent double submission of forms
jQuery.fn.preventDoubleSubmission = function () {
    $("button").click('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $form = $("#contactForm");

        // initialize validate
        $("form").validate();

        // bind to the form and run error function
        $($form).bind("invalid-form.validate", function() {
            if( $("invalid-form.validate") )
            formErrors();
        })

        if ($form.data('submitted') === true) {
            // Previously submitted - don't submit again
        } else {
            if ($form.valid()) {
                // Mark it so that the next submit can be ignored
                $form.data('submitted', true);

                // Make ajax call form submission
                $.ajax({
                    url: $form.attr('action'),
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    data: $form.serialize(),
                    success: function (result) {
                        success();
                    }
                });
            }
        }       
    });

    // keep chainability
    return this;
};

function hover() {
  $(".contour-button").on("mouseenter", function() {
  return $(this).addClass("hover");
  });
}

function hoverOff() {
  $(".contour-button").on("mouseleave", function() {
    return $(this).removeClass("hover");
  });
}

function success() {
    $(".contour-button").addClass("success");
    $(".contour-btn-arrow").addClass("contour-btn-success");
    $(".contour-button .submit").html("Thank you for your enquiry");
}

function formErrors() {
    $(".contour-button").addClass("form-errors");
    $(".contour-btn-arrow").addClass("contour-btn-error");
    $(".contour-button .submit").html("Please complete the form");
}

hover();
hoverOff();
```

HTML:

```
<div class="contour australia" id="contour_form_Australia">
  <form method="post" id="contactForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
    <input type="hidden" value="cNV3XRHLSNF43tj3o69gTg6xQS5fgXFZQpuJyJzhg90VFLl--TuJEeEHFFKzfEhBWYfVbVtXhKEWK8xl89z0NOAk4L88M67NoOfADsNulzQ1" name="__RequestVerificationToken">
    <input type="hidden" value="e3874303-234b-469d-9849-a0fe70f62695" name="FormId" id="FormId" data-val-required="The FormId field is required." data-val="true">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" id="FormStep" name="FormStep">
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="NextStep" name="NextStep">
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="PrevStep" name="PrevStep">
    <input type="hidden" id="RecordId" name="RecordId">
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="PreviousClicked" name="PreviousClicked">
    <div class="contourPage">
      <h4 class="contourPageName"></h4>
      <fieldset class="contourFieldSet">
        <div class="contourField name textfield mandatory">
          <label class="fieldLabel" for="abc6b8ed-5c99-460c-bd80-257747b07466">Name: <span class="contourIndicator">*</span></label>
          <div>
            <input type="text" data-val-required="Name: is mandatory" data-val="true" maxlength="500" value="" class="text" id="abc6b8ed-5c99-460c-bd80-257747b07466" name="abc6b8ed-5c99-460c-bd80-257747b07466">
            <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="abc6b8ed-5c99-460c-bd80-257747b07466" class="field-validation-valid"></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="contourField email textfield mandatory alternating">
          <label class="fieldLabel" for="dbd7b2e5-6a26-413a-b738-bc7441e4eace">Email: <span class="contourIndicator">*</span></label>
          <div>
            <input type="text" data-regex="^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$" data-val-regex="Email: is not valid" data-val-required="Email: is mandatory" data-val="true" maxlength="500" value="" class="text" id="dbd7b2e5-6a26-413a-b738-bc7441e4eace" name="dbd7b2e5-6a26-413a-b738-bc7441e4eace">
            <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="dbd7b2e5-6a26-413a-b738-bc7441e4eace" class="field-validation-valid"></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="contourField company textfield">
          <label class="fieldLabel" for="0fd5e8ed-e9d3-4bf9-825b-7eb3bf73ed46">Company: </label>
          <div>
            <input type="text" maxlength="500" value="" class="text" id="0fd5e8ed-e9d3-4bf9-825b-7eb3bf73ed46" name="0fd5e8ed-e9d3-4bf9-825b-7eb3bf73ed46">
            <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="0fd5e8ed-e9d3-4bf9-825b-7eb3bf73ed46" class="field-validation-valid"></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="contourField phone textfield alternating">
          <label class="fieldLabel" for="7072d283-91f1-4c30-a638-9681ca0fe76f">Phone: </label>
          <div>
            <input type="text" data-regex="/^(?=.*[0-9])[- +()0-9]+$/" data-val-regex="Phone: is not valid" data-val="true" maxlength="500" value="" class="text" id="7072d283-91f1-4c30-a638-9681ca0fe76f" name="7072d283-91f1-4c30-a638-9681ca0fe76f">
            <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="7072d283-91f1-4c30-a638-9681ca0fe76f" class="field-validation-valid"></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="contourField message textarea mandatory">
          <label class="fieldLabel" for="05ce7d9f-b381-4c14-bc37-36f0270fc19a">Message: <span class="contourIndicator">*</span></label>
          <div>
            <textarea data-val-required="Message: is mandatory" data-val="true" cols="20" rows="2" id="05ce7d9f-b381-4c14-bc37-36f0270fc19a" name="05ce7d9f-b381-4c14-bc37-36f0270fc19a"></textarea>
            <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="05ce7d9f-b381-4c14-bc37-36f0270fc19a" class="field-validation-valid"></span></div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <div style="display:none" class="contourField">
        <label for="e3874303-234b-469d-9849-a0fe70f62695">Message</label>
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="e3874303-234b-469d-9849-a0fe70f62695" id="e3874303-234b-469d-9849-a0fe70f62695">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contourNavigation"> 
      <!-- <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeOivMSAAAAAGMp47EfxRiGiHhiUSJF7hFuidPV"></div> --> 
      <!-- <input class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Submit"/> -->
      <button class="contour-button" type="button">
      <div class="submit">Submit</div>
      <div class="contour-btn-arrow">
        <div class="top line"></div>
        <div class="bottom line"></div>
      </div>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="formSubmittedMsg"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fieldLabel {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.contourField div input {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 10px 0;
    border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #555;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

/* normal text area */
div.contourField.message.textarea.mandatory div textarea {
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 287px;
    border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #555;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;

    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.contourField.textfield {
    width: 45%;
}

.contourField.message.textarea.mandatory {
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
}

@media (max-width: 670px) {
    .contourField.textfield {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .contourField.message.textarea.mandatory {
        float: right;
        position: inherit;
        width: 50%;
    }
    .contourField.message.textarea.mandatory {
        width: 100%;
    }
    div.contourField.message.textarea.mandatory div textarea {
        height: 150px !important;
    }
}

.contourField div input:focus, div.contourField.message.textarea.mandatory div textarea:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(243,116,33,0.2);
    border: 1px solid rgba(243,116,33,0.75);
}

.contourField.textfield.mandatory > div {
    position: relative;
}

/* input box validation error */
.field-validation-error {

    -moz-transition: all .3s ease; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease; /* WebKit */
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 0.3s ease; /* Standard */

    font-size: 14px;
    background: #f4d6d6 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    border-left: 1px solid #e3a6a6;
    color: #935656;
    padding: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 1px;
    top: 11px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* text area validation error */
div.contourField.message.textarea.mandatory div span.field-validation-error {

    top: 35px !important;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;

    -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 3px !important;
    border-radius: 0 3px !important;
}

.input-validation-error {

    border: 1px solid #e3a6a6 !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(277,166,166,0.2);
}

.input-validation-error:hover,.input-validation-error:focus,.input-validation-error:active, {
    border: 1px solid #e3a6a6 !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(277,166,166,0.2);
}

.contourIndicator {
    color: red;
}

.g-recaptcha {
    margin: 20px 0;
    float: left;
}

#contour fieldset, .contour fieldset {
    padding: 0 !important;
    position: relative;
}

.contourPageName {
    display:none;
}

.contourFieldSet p {
    margin: -10px 0 30px 0;
}

/* .submit-btn {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    color: #6a737b !important;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    float: right;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.submit-btn:hover {
    color: #ffffff !important;
    background: #6a737b;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.submit-btn-success {
    background: #d6f4d6 none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
    border: 1px solid #a6e3ac !important;
    color: #569369 !important;
} */

#formSubmittedMsg {
    background: #d6f4d6 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #a6e3ac;
    color: #569369;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: none;
}

.submit-btn-success:hover,.submit-btn-success:focus,.submit-btn-success:active {
    background: #d6f4d6 none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
    border: 1px solid #a6e3ac !important;
    color: #569369 !important;
}

/**** Button Style/Animation ****/

.contour-button {
    outline: 0;
    background: #3a4247 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: #ffffff !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    height: 43px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px 15px !important;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;

    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

/* mozilla only hack */
/* @-moz-document url-prefix() { 
    .contour-button {
        padding: 13px;
    }
} */

/* chrome only hack */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
    .contour-button {
        margin-top: 20px;
        padding: 13px 15px !important;
    }
}

/* ie 8,9,10 only hack */
@media screen\0 {
    .contour-button {
        margin-top: 10px;
        padding: 12px 15px !important;
    }

    .contour-btn-arrow {
        top: -17px !important;
    }
}

.submit,
.contour-btn-arrow {
    /* display: inline-block; */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.contour-btn-arrow {
    left: 85px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -13px;
}

.contour-btn-success {
    left: -34px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 54px;
}

.line {
    height: 3px;
    width: 11px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background: #ffffff;
}

.top {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.bottom {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    margin-top: 4px;
}

.contour-button:success {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.contour-button.hover .submit {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-90px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-90px);
    transform: translateX(-90px);
    opacity: 0; 
}

.contour-button.hover .contour-btn-arrow {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-70px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-70px);
    transform: translateX(-70px);
    opacity: 1;
}

.contour-button.success .contour-btn-arrow {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(70px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(70px);
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(70px);
}

.contour-button.success {
    background: #4CAF50;
    padding-left: 50px !important;
    width: 230px;
}

.contour-button.success .submit {
    opacity: 1;
}

.contour-button.success .top {
    width: 19px;
}

.contour-button.success .bottom {
    margin: 7px 0 0 8px;
}

.contour-btn-error {

}

/* if errors */

.contour-button.form-errors {
    background: #c73b3b;
}
```

Comment: Which jquery plugin have you used?

Comment: JQuery UI, JQuery Form, JQuery Validate (and unobstructive)

Comment: can you insert your code in a snippet of jsfiddle (including those plugin)?

Comment: Sorry it took so long, had some errors in the code and had to source the libraries - https://jsfiddle.net/t5k2j9uw/

Comment: I cannot understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I don't want the hover class to be active after the button changes to the error state or the success state. You shouldn't be able to hover once there's an error or once the form has successfully submitted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the following css rules adding the :not() selector to avoid the rule to be applied on success and on error.

Result: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t5k2j9uw/1/)

```
.contour-button.hover:not(.form-errors):not(.success) .submit  {
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-90px);
 -moz-transform: translateX(-90px);
 transform: translateX(-90px);
 opacity: 0;    
}

.contour-button.hover:not(.form-errors):not(.success) .contour-btn-arrow{
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-70px);
 -moz-transform: translateX(-70px);
 transform: translateX(-70px);
 opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks silvia! Exactly what I wanted. :)